# expand collapsed data in nushell

Tags: nushell

I'm trying to learn nushell, and from this example in the documentation,

```
> echo [[column1, column2]; [Value1, Value2]]
───┬─────────┬─────────
 # │ column1 │ column2
───┼─────────┼─────────
 0 │ Value1  │ Value2
───┴─────────┴─────────
```

but my output is:

```
echo [[column1, column2], [Value1, Value2]]  
╭───┬────────────────╮
│ 0 │ [list 2 items] │
│ 1 │ [list 2 items] │
╰───┴────────────────╯
```

How do you expand the collapsed information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want to do is convert a Nushell list of lists to a table (a list of records).  I'm a bit surprised myself that there isn't (at least that I could find), an easier way (i.e. a built-in command) to do this coercion, but there are several ways to accomplish it.  However, I still feel that there's an easier way that I'm just not seeing myself.

Anyway, the easiest that I could come up with, for your particular example:

```
〉[[column1, column2], [Value1, Value2]] | each { { 0: $in.0, 1: $in.1 }} | headers
╭───┬─────────┬─────────╮
│ # │ column1 │ column2 │
├───┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 0 │ Value1  │ Value2  │
╰───┴─────────┴─────────╯
```

Note, in most cases, you can drop the `echo` commands and have exactly the same results.

Also note that there may be a simpler answer by transforming the data *earlier*, but you don't mention the source of the data.  It's unlikely that the original source of the data would be a Nushell "list literal" in the "real world".  But for purely academic/learning purposes, it's certainly worth understanding.

---

*Explanation:*

The first data type you have above (from the doc example) is truly a Nushell table:

```
〉[[column1, column2]; [Value1, Value2]] | describe
table<column1: string, column2: string>
```

The second is a list of lists:

```
〉 [[column1, column2], [Value1, Value2]] | describe
list<list<string>>
```

Also note that the doc example above *might* be considered a bit outdated.  When it was written, it was the only way to construct a table-literal in Nushell (and is still probably considered the "table-literal" syntax).  But the addition of the record-syntax in [0.40](https://www.nushell.sh/blog/2021-11-16-nushell_0_40.html) brought us a new way to specify a table literal, as a "list of records".  You can now use the (IMHO) more readable (or at least "standard"):

```
[{ 'column1':'value1', 'column2':'value2' }]
```

That said, the `[[column1, column2]; [Value1, Value2]]` form is more *concise* if you ever really needed to specify multiple rows for the table.  But whether or not this is a "real world" use is another question, and it wouldn't surprise me to see the "old" table-literal syntax removed before Nushell reaches 1.0.

It's that new "list-of-records" form that we use to answer your question:

```
[[column1, column2], [Value1, Value2]] | each { { 0: $in.0, 1: $in.1 }} | headers
```

- For each pair (e.g. `[Value1, Value2]`) in the list, creates a record with the first value set as key `0` and the second set as key `1`.
- The results from `each` are automatically collected into a list.
- Because the end result is a "list of records where every record is the same type", it results in a table.  If one of the rows was different (e.g. it had an integer instead of a string), then the results would *look* the same, but the actual output would be a "list of records".
- The `headers` command is used to take *your* heading names and use them instead of `0` and `1`.

Bonus:

The following will display lists with an arbitrary number of values:

```
[[Column1, Column2, Column3 ], [Value1, Value2], [Value3, Value4, Value5], [Value6]] |
    each { |values|
        reduce -f {} { |it,acc|
            $acc | insert $"Field($acc | transpose | length)" $it
        }
    } | headers
```

Result:

```
╭───┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────╮
│ # │ Column1 │ Column2 │ Column3 │
├───┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 0 │ Value1  │ Value2  │         │
│ 1 │ Value3  │ Value4  │ Value5  │
│ 2 │ Value6  │         │         │
╰───┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────╯
```

Explanation (in case you aren't familiar with `reduce` yet):

- Loops over each (inner) list of values in the (outer) list
- "Reduces" each of those inner lists of values to a record:

  - Starts with an empty record `-f {}` as `$acc`
  - Inserts each field as `Field0`, `Field1`, and so on.
  - The results are appended to the `$acc` which becomes the complete record at the end of the reduction.
  - The `| transpose | length` is a hacky workaround due to a bug that I need to file.  I'll link it back here when I do.